# What does `=>` mean in scala generics?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

Reading both the documentation for Scalaz and Cats, I notice that they frequently use `=>` in their generic/polymorphic field. For example, from the [scalaz page on applicatives](https://scalaz.github.io/8/tc/Applicative.html), it has the following definition for `ap`:

```
override def ap[A, B](fa: ZipList[A])(f: ZipList[A => B]): ZipList[B] =
    ZipList((fa.value zip f.value).map(t => t._2(t._1)))
```

Now, I think understand the use of `=>` inside the map, here its acting as part of a lambda, and I can guess that the `=>` on the first line is adding the requirement that `A` and `B` be for a function. But I can't seem to find any documentation confirming this.

So, what is the purpose of `=>` when used inside a generic/polymorphic field definition in Scala?

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/scala/ `val sq: Int => Int = x => x * x`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A => B` is the same as `Function1[A, B]`, that is the type of a function taking an `A` and returning a `B`.

Comment: A function and a function type are different :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images